# What exactly is a Definition in the context of Document Flow?

Tags: html, css

[This website](https://soulandwolf.com.au/blog/what-is-document-flow/) uses the word "Definition" but never defines it:

> Document flow is the arrangement of page elements, as defined by CSS positioning statements, and the order of HTML elements. this is to say, how each Definition takes up space and how other elements position themselves accordingly.

I need the literal words that I can replace the word "Definition" with in this sentence, and the sentence would still be saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean "element". I'm not sure why they used the word "definition" there... poor copy editing, I suppose. MDN has a more comprehensive explanation on this (and for any HTML or CSS-related topic) if you are interested in learning more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow

Answer (score 0):

How each implementation of the elements in the html doc, with the css or js attached to those elements.

Comment: What is an `implementation`?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).